# Use ssh to launch remote process and exit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to use `ssh` from the command line to launch a python server on a remote server using the following command:

```
$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-o ConnectTimeout=5 -f -i mykey.pem user@99.99.99.99 \
'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000 & echo $! > /home/user/pysrv.pid'
```

After the launch my `ssh` session goes to the background but does not exit until the python server is running. Is there a way I can setup the command so that ssh does not stick around as a background process on my current machine?

Comment: You can use screen or close all file descriptors [see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000 & echo $! > /home/user/pysrv.pid &
```

It will create a detached task that doesn't need the parent (ssh).

OTOH, if you kill the ssh server process, you won't be able to connect again. Is this what you want, or are you just trying to kill the session? If it's just the session, it should go away by itself after the connection is dropped.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does not help. I still see the ssh process in the background.

Comment: Does ps show a "?" or a real PID? The "?" tasks are just wanting for cleanup.

Comment: wanting -> waiting

Comment: Actually it shows a PID but a ? in the TTY column. Also the strange thing is that the python process in the remote server also shows the ? and I cannot send request to it!

Comment: The TTY ? means the process isn't attached to a session, which is why you can't talk to it and should be able to disconnect and leave it running.

Comment: I think tty is ? because ssh was executed as -f to fork as a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh` command exits when the TCP connection is closed. If you redirect `stdin` and `stderr` of the remote command, nothing will be connected to the TCP connection and it will close.

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 -f -i mykey.pem user@99.99.99.99 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000  2>/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null& echo $! > /home/user/pysrv.pid'
```

Comment: That did not work either the ssh process was still active in the process list.

Comment: We need to redirect the python process's I/O, not the echo. Try the updated answer.